# referencing observable in data-bind attribute

Tags: knockout.js

I tried browsing the web and knockout documentation, but i couldn't find an explanation. I see in some places where:

```
data-bind="with: SomeProperty">
```

vs.

```
data-bind="with: SomeProperty()"> // note ( )
```

What's the distinction between the two? When to use the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, `SomeProperty` can just be a regular property or an `observable` property of your `viewModel`. Knockout *unwraps* it and binds the value to DOM. The only difference being, if it's an `observable`, the UI will be updated when the property changes.

```js
var vm = {
  observableProperty: ko.observable({
    innerProp: 10
  }),
  regularProperty: {
    innerProp: 10
  },

  update: function() {
    this.observableProperty({
      innerProp: 20
    });

    // will not update the DOM
    this.regularProperty = {
      innerProp: 20
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: observableProperty">
  Observable: <span data-bind="text: innerProp"></span>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: observableProperty()">
  Observable with parenthesis: <span data-bind="text: innerProp"></span>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: regularProperty">
  Normal: <span data-bind="text: innerProp"></span>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: update">update</button>
```

In the second scenario, `SomeProperty` has to be an observable because you are evaluating it.

Comment: Does this mean there is zero benefit to using the `()` when binding with `with`?

Comment: To add on @John. Would `data-bind ="with: observableProperty().SomeNestedObject` behave same as `data-bind ="with: observableProperty.SomeNestedObject`?

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary no, those two aren't the same. Because `observables's` are functions. There is no `SomeNestedObject` in `observableProperty`, only in `observableProperty()`. The former will return `undefined`.

Comment: @JohnPavek Not that I know of. (Unless this is a rhetorical question and you do know some difference, in which case, please tell :) )

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary sorry, I got the order mixed up. `observableProperty.SomeNestedObject` will return `undefined`

Comment: @adiga sorry for some confusion. The assumption is `observableProperty` has an object property `SomeNestedObject = { someProp = ..., someOtherProp = ..} ` in addition to `innerProp`.

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary it doesn't matter. If you want to access inner property of an observable, you need to do `observableProperty().SomeNestedObject`. There is no `SomeNestedObject` in `observableProperty`. It exists only in `observableProperty()` object.